# Can someone help me decipher what these netgear log entries mean? Am I getting hacked?

Tags: network, denial-of-service

Can someone help me decipher what these log entries mean? Am I getting hacked?

So this is my residential router is a netgear gateway C3700-100NAS with Spectrum Internet. Usually I have no problems. But every so often, intermittently and not very predictable, I would notice my Internet slow down to a crawl, and even pinging 8.8.8.8 or www.yahoo.com will time out or have insane times.

I checked my netgear gateway C3700-100NAS logs and saw this.... Apparently in the span of less than a minute or so there were hundreds of entries for Source of "140.3.230.0" and Target/Destination of "149.104.249.105". Neither of these IPs have anything to do with my residential IP address nor would/should any device on my network be sending nor receiving anything to or from any of these IP addresses.

Based on a simple lookup it appears that 149.104.249.105 is Location is Washington D.C. (Northwest Washington), District of Columbia US - ISP is Cogent Communications and that 140.3.230.0 is Location is Columbus, Ohio US - ISP is DoD Network Information Center.

Can anyone have any idea what is going on?

[image]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/5QuHJ.jpg

=== update =====

But one of the problem is I'm with TWC /Spectrum and they statically assign public IP addresses so I'm stuck with the one I have gotten. The only time that I ever gotten a new IP was when my previous router died and when I got a replacement router I had to call them in with the MAC/ CM MAC info and that is after they registered the new Router on their end (also the same C3700 netgear model) I noticed when going to whatismyipaddress that I gotten a new public IP address. It doesn't happen all the time but when it does happen it slows me down to a crawl and usually a reboot stops it, but not because it changed to a different IP address (its static)

The other thing I thought was strange is that assuming the IP address are legit and not spoofed or anything, apparently based on whatever public records available it appears to be coming from a government network going to another government network

All of them are Source of "140.3.230.0" and Target/Destination of "149.104.249.105"

[image]

Answer (score 8):

At first glance, your home network seems to be used for a Denial of Service (DoS) attack. If this is the case, you already have been hacked.

**What should I do?**

- If you want, you may let your ISP know about it --> [here](http://www.spectrum.net/support/general/reporting-internet-abuse/). Your ISP might be interested helping you block an attack on a Department of Defense server.
- Use Wireshark to monitor the traffic on the devices connected to your router when crawling become slow. The device producing the most traffic is likely the culprit.
- Update your question with some .pcap samples when you find the culprit(s).

**What should I find with Wireshark, how do I find the culprit(s)?**

- You want to find ICMP/ping packets bigger than 65,536 bytes. (You need to understand how [PoD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ping_of_death) works.)
- If you find those ICMP sessions on a device, save the .pcap, take a screenshot and repeat the process on the remaining devices. You want to know how many devices have been compromised.
- If you find some malicious ICMP Session we want to see the details of the layer 2, 3 and 4.

**I found those malicious sessions you speak about on my device!(s)**

There is/are some malware(s) on your machine(s), find it, and nuke it.

**How do I nuke the malware?**

There is a lot of antivirus software available. But, from my point of view, the best way would be to totally wipe the compromised device(s).

**I found nothing on Wireshark.**

- Try again. Wireshark might not be easy to use, try to be familiar with the filters. In this case, filter for ICMP or PING traffic.

**I really found nothing on Wireshark, tried on all my devices, 5 times.**

Then, there is slight chance that your router is compromised. Attackers often attempt to hide their presence, and will attempt to suppress logging.

**So what if my router is compromised?**

- Be sure that your router firmware is up to date
- Reset your router to factory default.
- Don't use `admin` as login, set a brand new strong password.

**Could these attacks be coming through my WiFi AP?**

Yes, this could be performed by an uninvited device that is accessing your Wifi. Check your AP's WiFi DHCP/Static leases to be sure.

#### Important !

Try to not input passwords, credit card info, or other sensitive data on your devices before being 100% sure that your devices are clean. If malware is on your network doing the DOS, there is a good chance that a keylogger may be present, too.

Comment: Might I suggest to rephrase the sentences/questions you put in blockquotes? It's not really clear where they come from or if they are quotes from OP.

Comment: those quotations are there for simulating a dialog between the OP and me. The goal is to cover the questions the OP might have. I though it would be better to write the answer this way. @tom

Comment: I get that, but it took me a while to realize it and I even checked the question again, to see if I missed the parts you mentioned in you answer. It's just a proposal, not an order. ;)

Comment: I like this answer very much, so I removed the quotes to help make it more understandable.